# How does a rails server know which route.rb to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide

I'm currently learning rails following this tutorial: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#sec-the_hello_application

Here's what I've done.

1. Create a new workspace in Cloud9.
2. Use the `rails new hello_world` to create a new rails application.
3. From there configure routes.rb, application_controller.rb etc.
4. Create a new application in the same work space using `rails new sample_app`
5. Muck around changing stuff here as well.
6. Change to the hello_world directory, our directory is /workspace/hello_world.
7. Open new terminal, run `rails server -b $IP -p $PORT`
8. This successfully deploys a webapp, but when I access it shows the application from my `sample_app` application.

How do I specify which application I want to deploy?

Comment: So you ran the `rails new sample_app` command from the same directory that you ran `rails new hello_world`?

Comment: @MichaelHamilton Yip, at `/workspace`

Comment: You say in step 5 open new terminal, are you sure you are in the /workspace/hello_world directory when you are starting the server?

Comment: @MichaelHamilton Yip, defo

Comment: @MichaelHamilton Or not... silly typo by me. My bad. :/

Comment: Lol sure!  I was just posting an answer to this haha.  I was double checked this myself to make sure that is all that needed to be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are in the right directory.  You have created two applications in the same directory, so make sure you are starting the server from
    /workspace/hello_world

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate to `Cloud9/hello_world` to run the server on it.

Or `Cloud9/sample_app` to run the server on it.

You might have created sample_app inside hello_world in which case to run it you will need to navigate to `Cloud9/hello_world/sample_app` to run it on the server.